# Cannot autowire argument $famille of "App\Controller\HomeController::accueil()": it references class "App\Entity\Famille" but no such service exists

Tags: symfony5

Cannot autowire argument $famille of "App\Controller\HomeController::accueil()": it references class "App\Entity\Famille" but no such service exists.

here I'm trying to display the home page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4oAt.png)

---

> here's the controller file for the symfony project, ..... I don't think there are any syntax    errors.
> **src/Controller/HomeController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Famille;
use App\Repository\AnnonceRepository;
use App\Repository\BrandRepository;
use App\Repository\CategoryRepository;
use App\Repository\FamilleRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
/**
     * @Route("/home-{slug}", name="app_home", defaults={"slug": "femme"})
     */
    public function home(Famille $famille, Request $request): Response
    {

       $this->setFamilly($famille->getSlug());

        $sections = $famille->getSections();

        $step = 0;
        $produits = [];
        //Get last seen products
        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            
            $datas = json_decode($request->request->get('data'));
            $annonces = $this->productRepository->findByLastSeen($datas);

            foreach ($annonces as $annonce) {

                if($annonce) {

                    $titre = $annonce->getTitre();
    
                    $prix = $annonce->getPrix();
                    $prixPromo = $annonce->getPrixPromo();
    
                    $add['id'] = $annonce->getId();
                    $add['titre'] = $titre;
                    $add['imageName'] = $annonce->getImageName();
                    $add['marque'] = $annonce->getMarque()->getTitre();
                    $add['slug'] = $annonce->getSlug();
                    $add['prix'] = $prix;
                    $add['prixPromo'] = $prixPromo;
                    array_push($produits, $add);
                }
            }
            
            return new JsonResponse($produits);
        }

        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig',[
            'famille' => $famille,
            'products' => $this->productRepository->findBy(['famille' => $famille, 'top' => 1, 'valide' => 1], ['id' => 'DESC'], 8), 
            'beautyProducts' => $this->productRepository->findBy(['famille' => $famille, 'beaute' => 1, 'valide' => 1], ['id' => 'DESC'], 4), 
            'sections' => $sections,
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

> here is my Famille entity file codes....
> **src/Entity/Famille.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\FamilleRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=FamilleRepository::class)
 */
class Famille
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $titre;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $icon;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Category::class, mappedBy="famille")
     */
    private $categories;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Annonce::class, mappedBy="famille")
     */
    private $annonces;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Section::class, mappedBy="famille")
     */
    private $sections;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Parfum::class, mappedBy="famille")
     */
    private $parfums;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Card::class, mappedBy="famille")
     */
    private $cards;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Lien::class, mappedBy="famille")
     */
    private $liens;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Link::class, mappedBy="famille")
     */
    private $links;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->annonces = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->sections = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->parfums = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->cards = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->liens = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->links = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitre(): ?string
    {
        return $this->titre;
    }

    public function setTitre(string $titre): self
    {
        $this->titre = $titre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSlug(): ?string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    public function setSlug(?string $slug): self
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIcon(): ?string
    {
        return $this->icon;
    }

    public function setIcon(?string $icon): self
    {
        $this->icon = $icon;

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString() 
    {
        return $this->getTitre();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Category[]
     */
    public function getCategories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }

    public function addCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
            $this->categories[] = $category;
            $category->setFamille($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCategory(Category $category): self
    {
        if ($this->categories->removeElement($category)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($category->getFamille() === $this) {
                $category->setFamille(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Annonce[]
     */
    public function getAnnonces(): Collection
    {
        return $this->annonces;
    }

    public function addAnnonce(Annonce $annonce): self
    {
        if (!$this->annonces->contains($annonce)) {
            $this->annonces[] = $annonce;
            $annonce->setFamille($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAnnonce(Annonce $annonce): self
    {
        if ($this->annonces->removeElement($annonce)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($annonce->getFamille() === $this) {
                $annonce->setFamille(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Section[]
     */
    public function getSections(): Collection
    {
        return $this->sections;
    }

    public function addSection(Section $section): self
    {
        if (!$this->sections->contains($section)) {
            $this->sections[] = $section;
            $section->setFamille($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeSection(Section $section): self
    {
        if ($this->sections->removeElement($section)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($section->getFamille() === $this) {
                $section->setFamille(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Parfum[]
     */
    public function getParfums(): Collection
    {
        return $this->parfums;
    }

    public function addParfum(Parfum $parfum): self
    {
        if (!$this->parfums->contains($parfum)) {
            $this->parfums[] = $parfum;
            $parfum->setFamille($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeParfum(Parfum $parfum): self
    {
        if ($this->parfums->removeElement($parfum)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($parfum->getFamille() === $this) {
                $parfum->setFamille(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Card[]
     */
    public function getCards(): Collection
    {
        return $this->cards;
    }

    public function addCard(Card $card): self
    {
        if (!$this->cards->contains($card)) {
            $this->cards[] = $card;
            $card->setFamille($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeCard(Card $card): self
    {
        if ($this->cards->removeElement($card)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($card->getFamille() === $this) {
                $card->setFamille(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Lien[]
     */
    public function getLiens(): Collection
    {
        return $this->liens;
    }

    public function addLien(Lien $lien): self
    {
        if (!$this->liens->contains($lien)) {
            $this->liens[] = $lien;
            $lien->setFamille($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLien(Lien $lien): self
    {
        if ($this->liens->removeElement($lien)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($lien->getFamille() === $this) {
                $lien->setFamille(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Link[]
     */
    public function getLinks(): Collection
    {
        return $this->links;
    }

    public function addLink(Link $link): self
    {
        if (!$this->links->contains($link)) {
            $this->links[] = $link;
            $link->setFamille($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeLink(Link $link): self
    {
        if ($this->links->removeElement($link)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($link->getFamille() === $this) {
                $link->setFamille(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```